# Using two liquibase ChangeLog Trees for the same Database

Tags: jdbc, liquibase

We currently have two separate databases/schemas for our application. We have run into data inconsistencies with this setup, so we either need a transaction spanning both databases or to merge the databases. We don't want to use JTA transactions, since we are using a normal Tomcat. So our approach would be to merge the two databases/schemas into one.

Both databases/schemas are currently managed via Liquibase and we would like to maintain two separate ChangeLogs, since one set of entities is from a thirdparty tool and the other set is managed by us. We don't have any name conflicts, other than that liquibase uses its default tablenames.

So my question is, is using the `liquibase.databaseChangeLogTableName` and `liquibase.databaseChangeLogLockTableName` properties to define different tablenames for liquibase the best approach for this scenario?
http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/configurable-databasechangelog-table-name

Answer (score 0):

That does look like a reasonable approach - you would have to make sure that when you ran any liquibase commands that you always used the correct `liquibase.databaseChangeLogTableName` and `liquibase.databaseChangeLogLockTableName` with the corresponding changelog.